# zsh using CPU at 100% after starting atom editor

Tags: zsh, atom-editor

I have a small problem with `zsh`, it uses the CPU at 100% sometimes. In the image below:
[image: htop]

How can I solve it? I have killed it many times, but it always starting again.

The configuration file is simple, it's default from `oh-my-zsh` plus some stuff for `virtualenvwrapper` and `pyenv`:

```
 source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
 export PATH="/home/plugaru/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
 eval "$(pyenv init -)"
 eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

And yes, I am using `Atom` :)

Comment: could you past your .zshrc configuration file please?

Comment: If you do not wish to share your configuration file, you could verify it with https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh

Comment: You'll also help answerers by [edit]ing the question to confirm that yes, you are using atom.  (-:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This bug is the result of some questionable design in Atom.  It's not specific to the Z Shell, moreover.  People experience it with other shells, too.

Atom wants to know the environment variables of your interactive login shell for some reason.  To do this, it spawns an instance of your chosen shell, tells it to run the `env` command (after running all of its startup scripts) using the shell's `-c` command line option, and captures the output of that.  It tries to ensure that it doesn't hit any shell aliases, so it runs `command env`, and it tries to get the environment as it would be for a *login* shell by giving your chosen shell a `-l` command-line option as well.

The Atom developers found that people weren't setting their environment up correctly for *non-interactive* login shells.  To bodge around this, they made it *also* supply the shell with the `-i` option that tells the shell to think that it is an *interactive* login shell even if its standard I/O does not *appear* interactive.

Unfortunately, they happen to invoke an interactive shell in such a way that shells such as the Z Shell go the whole hog and try to read input interactively.  But Atom doesn't supply them with any input, just an end-of-file.

Enter the Z Shell's and the Bourne Again shell's `ignoreeof` options as the final element of this comedy.  These options mean that the shells *keep trying* to read input, even if they get end-of-file on standard input.  They do so in a pretty tight loop.  Hence the CPU usage.

## Further reading

- Daniel Stone (2016-10-27).  *[Shelling out to collect environment variables is creating runaway 100% CPU processes on Linux](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/13084)*.  Atom bug tracker. #13084.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for description. I haven't thought that the problem is in Atom.